# Is it possible to retrieve lost versioned data in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, sql, sql-server, database, versioning

One of my staff accidentally deleted a feature class she was creating in her version before I reconciled it.

I have grabbed a back up of the database from yesterday in SQL Management Studio. Is there a way to locate the table with the unreconciled data and restore it?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1